# Is it reasonable to have grunt/gulp build phases in javascript dev environment

Tags: web-development, javascript, development-process, automation, client-side

Nowdays it's goes to be very fancy to have grunt/gulp build phases who concatenate and minify and organize javascript code.

And I agree that this is important for production.

But as a developer, I see inconvenience there:

1. additional step to run code (execute gulp/grunt command)
2. hard to navigate in one concatenated files (even worse if it's
   minified)
3. Build procedure take time, especially if your project quite big and
   pc not very powerfull

So, is it important to have all that steps for development mode anyway, or will be reasonable to make it a part of release process, and avoid using it during development?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it from time to time in development to check that it works correctly and isn't adding any additional bugs.

It shouldn't be a step that you're using just in your release process, because that should be happening post-testing.

You shouldn't be doing it for every small change you make, but from time to time you should absolutely be checking your new code works correctly after it's been concatenated and minified.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to do this in development only if you are not 100% certain that the script-mangling step doesn't introduce errors.

Personally, I think using a tool that you can't be 100% certain of to transform your entire code base is unprofessional and you should never do it, but I recognize that getting the job done in the real world sometimes requires you to compromise your principles. Therefore my answer is not a straight "no, it's not necessary", but only "almost certainly no".

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, for client-side javascript concatenation and minification are important speed optimisations. No different to running gcc with optimising flags set in C. Deliberately not using them in production without a good technical reason isn't the sign of a professional developer.